# Problem including a gigya sdk in a cakephp application

Tags: php, cakephp, sdk, gigya, vendors

I am trying to include gigya php sdk in my application. The file is under /app/vendors/GSSDK.php I included it in my controller as

```
App::import('Vendor', 'GSSDK');
```

And in my view

```
$request = new GSRequest($apiKey,$secretKey,$method);
```

I get a error missing class GSRequest. I am facing problems including the php sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include vendor files into the correct directory `/vendors/` or `/app/vendors` both should work. Try including with different styles as sugguested by [book cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/view/538/Loading-Vendor-Files) and remember CASE does matter.